# Custom HTML5 validation pattern: YYYY.anynumber

Tags: regex, html, validation

I googled a lot, but I'm stuck.

There is a cool thing in HTML5, required patterns. It's great for emails / phones / dates validation. I use it in my small project for checking numbers. What I need is a pattern for:

```
YYYY.ordernumber
```

Order number may be any number from 1 to 1000000.

I tried to modify some `YYYY.MM` patterns for my case, but with no luck. What ever I type in does not pass the validation.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Added a lookahead to ensure 'ordernumber' is > 0 (thanks to [M42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/m42)'s remark in comments).

You can use those two attributes with your `<input>`:

```
pattern="^[0-9]{4}\.(?!0+$)([0-9]{1,6}|1000000)$"
required
```

E.g.

```
<input type="text" placeHolder="YYYY.ordernumber" title="YYYY.ordernumber"
       pattern="^[0-9]{4}\.(?!0+$)([0-9]{1,6}|1000000)$" required />
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Xx25g/)**.

---

Short explanation of the regex:

```
                  ^[0-9]{4}\.(?!0+$)([0-9]{1,6}|1000000)$    _____________
                  ^\______/\/\_____/ \________/\______/ ^___|match the end|
                  |    |    |   |_(*2)    |_       |_____   |of the string|
           _______|    |    |____           |            |
 _________|__   _______|_____   _|______   _|________   _|______
|match the   | |match exactly| |match a | |match 1 to| |or match|
|beggining of| |4 digits     | |dot (*1)| |6 digits  | |1000000 |
|the string  |
```

`(*1): '.' is a special character in regex, so it has to be escaped ('.').`
`(*2): This is a negative lookahead which does consume any characters, but looks ahead and makes sure that the rest of the string in not consisted of zeros only.`

---

*Just for the sake of completeness*:
I must point out the fact that `[0-9]` matches **only** digits 0-9. If you need to **also** match other digit characters, such as for example Eastern Arabic numerals (`٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`), you can use `\d` instead.

Comment: **+1** for the nice explanation

Comment: It will match `0` for ordernumber that is not wanted.

Comment: @DmitryHoronitel: Please, take a look at my updated answer, which makes sure 'ordernumber' is greater than 0.